# C# count listview item entry

Tags: asp.net

I want to display ListView row count on how many user, but i only got 0 value.
Example code:

```
Response.Write("Total User in List: " + ListView1.Items.Count());
```

Thanks for help.

NOTE: I'm placing it on .cs Page load
Sorry for the raw data, 
I didn't insert/add using code i just populate it manually on database

[image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PylK.png]]

Comment: Show us how you insert/populate the listview.  My guess is your datasource might be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code inside `IsPostBack` and then try

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!IsPostBack)
            {


                ListView1.DataSource = listUsers;
                ListView1.DataBind();

                Response.Write(ListView1.Items.Count);
            }
}
```